# How to append an existing XML file using DOM without overwriting the existing data?

Tags: java, xml, dom, append

I have created a simple XML file to which I am writing some tweets that i collect on every batch run. **I want the file to be appended rather than rewritten on every batch run**. At the moment it is overwriting the current document on every batch run.

Can help me out with this please !!

Comment: People would need to know which XML library you are using. Sample code always helps.

Comment: You'd probably have to do it "by hand". I'd suggest using other data storage other than a structured document (XML, JSON, YAML) for such task. Simple CSV might be better or simple DB. Document always has closing tag etc. at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
```

that will open the file in append mode.

Please note that it might cause a problem, if you have:

```
<root>
    <sometag></sometag>
</root>
```

and then you append the same structure again, the next time you read the file you'll get:

```
 <root>
        <sometag></sometag>
    </root>
 <root>
        <sometag></sometag>
    </root>
```

which is not valid. So if you need to parse this xml later, you'll have to do it this way:

1. Read entire xml content.
2. Add new element to document object (using DOM parser)
3. write updated document to file (overriding old data).